# How to declare type by callback function's argument type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

How to declare callback function ***handle***'s param type?

```
const util = (handle: (p) => string) => ({
  // I expect log function's param [p]'s type come from handle function's param's type
  log: (p: Parameters<typeof handle>[0]) => console.log(handle(p))
});

// But now the log function param is recognized as any type not string
const { log } = util((a: string) => String(a));
```

// Expect ***log*** function param is *string*
`const { log } = util((a: string) => String(a));`
// Expect ***log*** function param is *int*
`const { log } = util((a: int) => String(a));`
// Expect ***log*** function param is *object*
`const { log } = util((a: object) => String(a));`

I know that the type can be specified in a ***generic*** way, but I wonder if the type has been declared in the parameter signature of the callback function, can this type be forwarded?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const util = <T,>(handle: (arg:T) => string) => ({
  // I expect log function's param [p]'s type come from handle function's param's type
  log: (p: T) => console.log(handle(p))
});
```

You can just declare generic parameter, TS will infer it

Comment: Thank you for answer, this is what I do now, but I want to know if it can be implemented automatically by passing a callback function.

Comment: The type has been declared in the parameter signature of the callback function, can this type be forwarded?

Comment: But it is already automatic. There is no need to define any explicit generics.  `const result = util((arg: number) => 'hello') // {log: (p: number) => void;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using generic type

```
const util = <T>(handle: (p: T) => string) => ({
  // I expect log function's param [p]'s type come from handle function's param's type
  log: (p: T) => console.log(handle(p))
});

// Expect log function param is string
const { log } = util<Number>((a) => String(a));
log(1);   // Param type number

const { log: log1 } = util<String>((a) => String(a));
log1('1');    // Param type string

const { log: log2 } = util<Object>((a) => String(a));
log2({});  // Param type object

const { log: log3 } = util((a) => String(a));
log3('');   // Param type any
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, this is what I do now, but I want to know if it can be implemented automatically by passing a callback function.

Comment: You should not use `T=any`. TS will infer the type

Comment: @PankajPrakash you can also remove explicit generic parameter `util<String>` here.
Btw, use `string` or `number` types instead of `Number` and `String`. Capitalized types are types of classes and not of primitives